# Compile all C# files into one file?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to compile C# files into one single file that is ready to give to the user?

Comment: Are you looking for a tool to merge C# source code, or to merge the output assemblies?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way is to use [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx). This will merge multiple assemblies into a single one (think combining all DLLs and a main exe into a single exe).

Comment: A short but useful article from CodeProject: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mergingassemblies.aspx

Comment: sadly this will not work with WPF assemblies (up to version 2.11.0502).

Comment: In such cases, I use boxedapp or boxedapp packer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes :)   But you must put all your sources into a single assembly and compile it to an EXE.   Also note that the target system must also have the required .NET infrastructure installed.

Note that security policies on the target system may prevent the user from directly running your app.

Lastly, unless you "[NGEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf(VS.80).aspx)" your code, it will be [jitted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1zx9t92(VS.80).aspx) the first time it runs.  This will incur some startup time costs.  THese can be considerable in some instances.

Comment: The jitting that occurs should be no different than if the program were a set of assemblies - jitting occurs on a method-by-method basis when each method is first called. Presumably, methods will be called in the same sequence whether the program is packaged in a single .exe or several assemblies.

Comment: @Michael - unless there was an edit, the only reference to JIT relates to NGEN; in which case, no: it *won't* be jitted on a method-by-method basis...

Comment: @Marc - I was thinking that the NGEN comment implied that combining the assemblies into a single .exe would increase the startup time over having multiple assemblies. In other words, I was trying to say that whether you want or need NGEN is likely independent of whether your assemblies are merged.

Answer (score 2):

If your looking to also merge the .Net assemblies required by your app, you can use something like [This](http://www.xenocode.com/Products/Postbuild-for-NET/) to even compile in System.dll, System.Windows.Forms.dll, etc, so the end user wont even need .Net installed.

Comment: That is pretty cool, I just wish I had $1500.00 to throw around.

Comment: I guess Mono now offers a similar functionality, and Mono is free.

Answer (score 0):

I got this from a similar question (sorry to whoever posted the answer - I can't seem to find the original to link it here):

[how to embed your application’s dependent DLLs inside your EXE file](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx)

It is an excerpt from Jeffrey Richter's CLR Via C#. I have not tried it yet but looks very promising. I think it will work with WPF as well (about to find out for myself).

Comment: Hah! As soon as I post the comment I run accoss the original: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3283372/513847.