# Drawbacks, advantages, etc. between ILMerge or ResolveAssembly for embedding assemblies?

Tags: .net, merge, assembly-resolution, ilmerge

Currently I know of two methods of embedding assemblies into one application file: ILMerge and using the ResolveAssembly event.

I would like to know if anyone have had more success with one over the other.

Is there any drawbacks from using either one of those (performance, security, ...)?

From my point of view, it looks like we should always merge all the "private" assemblies into an application as it is more clean this way when the application is considered as a whole.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you talking about Assembly.Load(byte[])?  Yuck.

Comment: Yes, what is wrong with it? Please leave an answer detailing what you're thinking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've since found this [blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/microsoft_press/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition) from Jeffrey Richter and I think it answers adequately my question.